# Memory leak , timer in WPF

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, timer, memory-management

I have this problem. I develop WPF app with MVVM architecture. As MVVM framework I use Caliburn.Micro and on service  injection I use MEF.

In view model class I use Dispatcher Timer which call every 3 seconds service method. This service method send POST request on server and parse HTML response / deserialize JSON string with JSON.NET.

This method return observable dictionary, is type : string, Friend.

Friend class consist only string properties and also one image as BitmapImage type.

**Here is service method:**

```
     public MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend> LoadFriends(Account account)
        {

            var friends = new MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend>();
            var sortedFriends = new MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend>();

            const string allData = "&allData=1";

            var htmlStringResult = new StringBuilder();

            htmlStringResult = "GET HTML RESPOSE"

            if (htmlStringResult.Length > 3 && htmlStringResult.ToString() != "false")
            {
                try
                {
                    var jsonString = new StringBuilder();
                    jsonString.Append(htmlStringResult.Replace(@"s_", "m_"));

                    var friendsAsStringArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObservableDictionary<string, string[]>>(jsonString.ToString());

                    foreach (var friend in friendsAsStringArray)
                    {
                        var item = new KeyValuePair<string, Friend>(friend.Key, new Friend
                        {
                            IdUser = friend.Value[0],
                            Nick = friend.Value[1],
                            SefNick = friend.Value[1],
                            Status = int.Parse(friend.Value[2]),
                            Photo = friend.Value[3],
                            Sex = int.Parse(friend.Value[4]),
                            IsFriend = Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(friend.Value[5]) * -1)
                        });
                        friends.Add(item);
                    }


//sort item in dictionary  A-Z
                    var query = friends.OrderByDescending(f => f.Value.Status).ThenBy(f => f.Value.Nick);

                    foreach (var keyValuePair in query)
                    {
                        sortedFriends.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
                    }

                    //CLEAN OLD DATA
                    friends.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    throw exception;
                }
                return sortedFriends;
            }
            return new MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend>();
        }
```

In view model class I bind observable dictionary on listbox.  In this class I call in timer every 3 seconds service mehod **LoadFriend**.

I returns fresh data in observable dictionary and with this data I refresh dictionary which is bind on listbox.

**Here is view model class:**

```
[Export(typeof(IMessengerViewModel))]
public class MessengerViewModel : Screen, IViewModelIdentity,
    IMessengerViewModel, IHandle<Rp>, IHandle<string>
{
    private IPokecService _service;

    private MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend> _friends;
    private MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend> _freshFriends;

    private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MessengerViewModel(IPokecService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();

    }


    #region Timer

    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh contact list, check for new messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="eventArgs"></param>
    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //retrieve new data from server
        _freshFriends = _service.LoadFriends(Account);

        _friends.Clear();


        //refresh dictionary
        foreach (var freshFriend in _freshFriends)
        {
            _friends.Add(freshFriend);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I make a simple test:

- run app with timer
- run app without timer
- with timer but empty logic for
  timer_tick method

I check values in task manager and in ANTS Memory profiler, here are value:

**Task manager process:**

- App with timer

  - after start : 40,133K
  - after 5 minutes: 70,261K
  - after 10minutes: 74,288K

---

- App without timer

  - after start : 37,488K
  - after 5 minutes: 37,412K
  - after 10minutes: 37,760K

---

- App with timer but empty logic

  - after start : 37,474K
  - after 5 minutes:37,340K
  - after 10minutes: 37,476k

**ANTS Memory profiler - Privates bytes**

- App with timer

  - after start: 73,132MB
  - after 5 minutes: 97,72MB
  - after 10minutes: 100,12MB

---

- App without timer

  - after start : 67,24MB
  - after 5 minutes: 66,21MB
  - after 10minutes: 66,21MB

---

- App with timer but empty logic

  - after start : 67,3MB
  - after 5 minutes: 66,32MB
  - after 10minutes:66,41MB

I don’t know that this values are normal. Maybe I have memory leak in app.

My first idea was check images in Friend class, but image is store in BitmapImage class. This class doesn’t implements interface IDisposable, so I can’t call method Dispose on old items in dictionary.

Maximum of privates bytes was 124,12 MB I think its quite enough.

I never handling with memory usage in .NET, I don’t know what can be wrong.

Thank for help, if someone explain me this problem I would be very gratefull him/her.

I think call in my timer garbage collector, but I think it’s goog idea.

Size of one image is 5-10kB. And in dictionary is about 20-30 items.

**I download image from web, image uri is URL.**

```
 public BitmapImage ProfilePhoto ...{ get; set; }

            private BitmapImage CreateProfilePhoto()
            {
                var img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();

                img.UriSource = Photo == "0" ? DefaultPhoto.GetDefaultPhoto(Sex) : new Uri(PhotoURL, UriKind.Absolute);

                img.EndInit();

                return img;
            }

    ....

            ProfilePhoto = CreateProfilePhoto();
```

Comment: If you already have a memory profiler, why don't you use it to see what is 'leaked'? Use ANTS to take snapshots and see what objects are created, but not destroyed and draw your conclusions.

Comment: I try it, but I can’t find memory leak.. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is invaluable: [Finding Memory Leaks in WPF-Based Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx).

There are issues with `BitmapImage`.

Comment: Thank for idea. I download image from web, but I use .NET4.0 ...in this article talked about 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing I see in the snippets is that you end up keeping 2 dictionaries.

There is one in _friends and one in _freshfriends.

Depending on the size of the dictionnary, that could explain some of the difference. As a first step, is there any reason why _freshFriends is no a method local variable?